# How to open files from Finder into existing instance of Sublime Text 2?

Tags: finder, text-editor, sublimetext

I would like to be able to go into `Finder` and open files into an existing instance of `Sublime Text 2`, which has a side menu with all open files.  However, when I hit `Open With` -> `Sublime Text 2.app`, it opens a whole new instance of Sublime, which is not what I want.  I can certainly accomplish grouping of my documents in a single instance if I open them within the application but that requires more steps and time, i.e. is not always  as convenient as opening them from `Finder`.

Answer (score 7):

As shown in [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/402122/48132), you can set this behaviour by changing the `open_files_in_new_window` setting in Sublime Text to `false`. (Note that it's recommended that you override the setting in the `Settings - User` file rather than changing it in `Settings - Default`.)

Comment: thanks, it is not clear whether the prefs from the S.U. answer pertain to Finder or Sublime

Comment: Those are definitely Sublime Text's preferences, not the Finder's.

Comment: unfortunately, those instructions did not work for me.  see my comment on S.U.